# Hyperledger Composer development environment NPM error

Tags: npm, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Trying to setup development environment but getting the below error when running "npm install -g composer-cli@0.20"

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.5.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.5.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  I had installed the latest Node (10.13.0 LTS), whereas the pre-requisites says **Node: 8.9 or higher (note version 9 is not supported)**

After installing Version 8.9 (using NVM), was able to successfully install "composer-cli" package.